# Let $z_0$ be an isolated singularity of $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of $f$, $lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)^kf(x)$ exists, then $\exists g$ holo in a neighborhood of $z_0$ such that $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_o)^k}$ and $g(z_0) \neq 0$.

My attempt is to define that $g(z)=(z-z_0)^kf(x)$ while $z\neq z_0$ and $g(z) =lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)^kf(x)$ while $z=z_0$.But I do not know how to show that $g(z)$ is holomorphic at $z_0$.

Comment: show that $h(z) = (z-z_0)^{k+2} f(z)$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, or use the Cauchy integral formula for showing directly that $(z-z_0)^k f(z)$ is holomorphic

Comment: How to use Cauchy integral formula here?

Comment: since $\frac{g(z)}{z-a}$ is holomorphic everywhere except at $z_0$ and $a$, you have that for $|a-z_0| < r$ :  $\displaystyle\ \int_{|z-z_0| = r} \frac{g(z)}{z-a}dz =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|z-z_0| = \epsilon} \frac{g(z)}{z-a}dz+\int_{|z-a| = \epsilon} \frac{g(z)}{z-a}dz = g(a)$ and hence $g(z)$ is analytic/holomorphic everywhere

Comment: note I used that $h_a(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z-a}$ has a limit $l$ as $z \to z_0$, so that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|z-z_0| = \epsilon} h_a(z)dz = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|z-z_0| = \epsilon} (l+o(\epsilon))dz = 0$